# Where clause using Linq - search for a list of Object

Tags: c#, linq

One doctor can work in One hospitals.

The Doctor table looks like this:

```
Id
Name
Speciality
HospitalName
```

`HospitalName` is a string.

Hospital Table contains the following

```
Id
HospName 
Address
```

Now, I have a List of `Hospital` Objects. Where I need to filter it using a `List of Doctor`. I need to search from the `Doctors` table, where the `HospitalName` is equal to `HospName` in the Hospital table.

Code:

```
 List<Hospital> hos = listHospitals;
 var doctors = docList
.Where(h=> listHospitals.Contains(h.HospitalName));
```

I get an error that states :

> Can not convert form string to Hospital`

How can I solve this ?

Comment: `List<Doctor> doctors = docList.Where(doctor => hos.Any(hospital => hospital.HospName == doctor.HospitalName)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any()` like below.`listHospitals` is of type `List<Hospital>` and thus you will have to query that list to compare hospital name.

```
List<Hospital> hos = listHospitals;
 var doctors = docList
.Where(h=> listHospitals.Any(x => x.HospitalName == h.HospitalName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var list = docList.Where(d => listHospitals.FirstOrDefault(h => d.HospitalName == h.HospName) != null).ToList();
```

Comment: While `FirstOrDefault(Predicate) != null` is roughly as efficient as `Any(Predicate)`, the latter is far easier to read.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say to use `Count()` instead of `Any()` since a List has a `.Length` or `.Count` property thus not need to go through the `GetEnumerator()/MoveNext()/Dispose()` sequence required by `Any()`.

Resulting in the following code:

```
List<Hospital> hos = listHospitals;
var doctors = docList
                 .Where(h=> hos.Count(x => x.HospitalName == h.HospitalName) > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. If I hand you a stack of playing cards and ask you "are any of them the queen of spades" do you have to *count* how many queens of spades there are?  Of course not.  You would not *form a list of all of the queens of spades and then count that list*.  You would enumerate the cards until you found the first queen of spades and then stop.  More generally though your argument is nonsense. The fact that list has a `Count` property does not mean that the filter is O(1) to enumerate! The `Count` that takes a predicate is **more expensive than Any**.

Comment: I am interested to learn how people come to believe false things about programming.  Can you explain how it is that you came to believe that `Count` that takes a predicate could possibly be cheaper than `Any` that takes a predicate?  `Count` has to do *more work* than `Any` so it cannot be cheaper; why did you believe that it was cheaper?  I use this information to help write better books, articles and other educational materials.